# Send a request to webservice via an xml file?

Tags: python, xml, web-services

I have a webservice running at `"tcs-webdev2:8200/scheduler/requestgroup"` to which new build requests can be sent using an xml file(sample xml file below). I need some guidance
on how requests to a webserive via n xml file work.

Sample xml file:-

```
<BuildInfo>
    <BuildSource>DEV_CI</BuildSource> 
    <SoftwareProductBuild>MAAAAANLGD0000211.1_101</SoftwareProductBuild>
    <PriorrootBuild>MAAAAANLGD0000211.1</PriorrootBuild>
    <NewSIBuilds>
        <Image>
            <Type>LNX</Type>
            <SoftwareImageBuild>buildlocation</SoftwareImageBuild>
            <Location>\\\sever\buildlocation\checkout</Location>
            <Variant>Default</Variant>
            <LoadType>Debug</LoadType>
        </Image>
    </NewSIBuilds>
</BuildInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your web service, how exactly you need to send the request, but you have to something like the following:

```
import httplib

with open("your_xml_filename.xml") as f:
    body = f.read()
headers = {"Content-type": "application/xml"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("tcs-webdev2", 8200)
conn.request("POST", "/scheduler/requestgroup", body, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print( response.status )
print( response.read())
conn.close()
```

It assumes that tcs-webdev2 is a valid hostname (if not, you can use the IP address). Also this request is an HTTP POST, your service might need different request type. Also some additional headers and authentication might be needed.

Comment: tcs-webdev2 is a valid hostname but I get the below error,how to debug this?what else can I try?
**<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>**

Comment: You should find out what your webservice expects. Invalid url means that "/scheduler/requestgroup" not good. You can try "/scheduler/requestgroup.xml". But really depends on the webservice, find more detail about it.

Comment: Also what happens when you enter tcs-webdev2:8200/scheduler/requestgroup to your browser?

Comment: when I enter it in browser..<Error><Message>The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.</Message></Error>

Comment: Change the URL to "/scheduler/requestgroups". You seem to have a resource API (REST), it's conventional to use plural when creating a resource.